# Two Nested IF Statements in Excel: Not Detecting All Satisfied Instances

Tags: excel, if-statement, text

I've got results from a task where the participant had to report whether or not a certain "target" was present or absent. I'd like to compare their response to the actual state of the target (present or absent), and classify their responses as either "Hit" "Miss" "Correct Rejection" or "False Alarm". I'm using two IF statements nested inside another IF statement.

Right now, Excel is only returning the "value_if_false" for each of the nested IF statements.

```
=IF(G6=F6,IF(F6="Present", "Hit", "Correct Rejection"),IF(F6="Present","Miss","False Alarm"))
```

[Here is a screenshot of what I've got going on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJvGJ.jpg)

I've done a lot of searching to find a solution and have tried several different strategies to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to nested `IF` statements. You have either leading or trailing (or both) white spaces in the text in the cells you are comparing.

Instead of cell *F6* containing the text "Absent", it is actually `" Absent"` or `"Absent "`, or a mixture of the two.

To fix do one of:

1. Use the `TRIM` function in your `IF` statement.
2. Remove the extra spaces from your cells.
3. Add the white spaces to your `IF` statement.

Fix 1 is easiest, probably. So your formula should be changed to
`=IF(TRIM(G6)=TRIM(F6),IF(TRIM(F6)="Present","Hit","Correct Rejection"),IF(TRIM(F6)="Present","Miss","False Alarm"))`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was so simple. I had considered this possibility but thought I had ruled it out with a "Find and Replace," but apparently not. Thank you for your help!